# Rails 4 hangs on repeated browser refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In production, on my local machine running on Windows 7 64-bit with Ruby 2.0.0, after a few repeated browser refreshes, my rails application hangs. The console shows something like this:

```
Error during failsafe response: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

whereas my production log says:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds
```

I changed the pool size in database.yml which resulted in hangs after a proportionately greater number of browser refreshes, but it would still hang up.

The application runs fine in development.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgres 9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to my **environments/production.rb** file solved the issue:

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
```

After adding this, my console is now showing issues with my applications that weren't shown previously, such as some missing assets. However, despite those issues, there are no application hangs no more.

**HOWEVER**
This is a temporary workaround... as adding this option on a live production application would result in error messages getting printed out to the wild world.

Comment: That won't fix the error - it will just mask it? If you've changed your db "pool size", it basically means you've set the number of connections your db can handle concurrently, which is why it probably hangs

Comment: I was of the same opinion until I figured out that some strange error was **secondarily** causing my idle database connections to not close, resulting in their getting used up. I have read about this issue elsewhere that it's a logging related bug which manifests itself ambiguously.

Comment: ohhh right - so it was keeping the connections open, thus leading to the refresh error? Okay